# Liferay 6.2 + MySQL "Database connection could not be established. Please check your connection settings."

Tags: mysql, jdbc, liferay

I'm trying to connect Liferay 6.2 to MySQL, but when in the basic configuration I press "Finish configuration" almost instantly I receive the following message:

> Database connection could not be established. Please check your connection settings.

I've made a database on MySQL called `lportal`, to not change JDBC URL :

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
```

I've checked MySQL user name too, everything is alright.
Catalina.out says: java.net.ConnectException

```
STACKTRACE:

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor96.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:355)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2461)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor77.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:211)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connessione rifiutata
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:305)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: You have forgotten port to be added beside localhost, like: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false

Comment: Please check this answer here I have mentioned  details steps for posgresql. You can follow same for Mysql.

Comment: I've tryed to put the port beside localhost
jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false

8080 is tomcat port , I'm using liferay with tomcat . But I still have the same answer from liferay

Comment: Any exception in the log?

Comment: You'll need the 3309 for mysql, not 8080 for tomcat in that string. This is the connection to your database, not your appserver.

Comment: I've tryed with3309 but stil the same

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connessione rifiutata
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.ja

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional information like stacktraces. And the exception indicates that your database server is not listening on localhost with port 3309. You should check the configuration of your database server for the correct port and network interface.

Comment: AFAIK, mysql port would be 3306, try with 3306 port, it should work..

Comment: I've tryed to use 3306 and ip address but still the same ... :(

Comment: That means you mysql server is not running or you have to specify correct port

Comment: To run mysql server I just need to write mysql -u root -p on the shell? Or it isn't enough?

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding that connectivity information to `portal-ext.properties`, then you also need to specify mySQL `username` and `password`, as following:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.password=test
```

But, first make sure of the port on which your mySQL database is running. The default port number is `3306`. However, you can also verify / change your mySQL port in `my.ini` located in root of your mySQL installation directory. Find `[mysqld]` and below it will be the port number.

```
[mysqld]

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
```